# How to solve this using integral test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum is from 2 to infinity and nth term is given by $ \log({ \frac{n+1}{n-1}} )\times n^{-1/2} $

Any ideas or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: is it $n+(1/n)-1$ or $\frac{n+1}{n-1}$?

Comment: The tricky part here is to find the anti-derivative. Try using integration by parts, it seems to solve this integral.

Comment: @angryavian the second one

Answer (score 3):

Letting $a_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\frac{\ln\frac{n+1}{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}$, you have
$$
a_n = \frac{\ln\!\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\frac{2}{n}+o(1)}{\sqrt{n}} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}.
$$
By comparison, this alone allows you to conclude the series converges. Are you required to use an integral comparison?

Comment: Thanks question stated to use integral test . but this way is also acceptable for me atleast